# Selenium WebDriver - How to identify the element from custom drop-down. DIV, UL and LI

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to Automate a custom drop-down field which has DIV, UL and LI. I am unable to use Select class or CSSSelector as this dynamically change.

```
    <div id="boundlist-1092" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box x-boundlist-above" tabindex="-1" style="right: auto; left: 495px; top: 245px; height: auto; z-index: 29001; width: 150px;">
<div id="boundlist-1092-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul class="x-list-plain">
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Single</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Married Filing Jointly</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Married Filing Separately</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Head of Household</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Qualifying Widow(er)</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

But, when the element is visible the HTML code looks different

```
    <div id="boundlist-1092" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box x-boundlist-above" tabindex="-1" style="right: auto; left: 495px; top: 245px; height: auto; z-index: 29001; width: 150px;">
<div id="boundlist-1092-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; height: auto;">
<ul class="x-list-plain">
<li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" unselectable="on" role="option">Single</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Married Filing Jointly</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Married Filing Separately</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Head of Household</li>
<li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">Qualifying Widow(er)</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

It would be of great help if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the dropdown, you can apply a *partial match* with an XPath expression:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "boundlist-")]
```

Here we are asking to get a `div` element with an `id` attribute starting with `boundlist-`.

To locate dropdown elements inside, I'd use a text match:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "boundlist-")]//li[. = "Married Filing Jointly"]
```

where `.` refers to the current element's text.

Comment: Thank you very much alecxe. Your code worked like a charm. Thanks a ton.